# Copying and modifying a jQuery object while retaining original Scope

Tags: jquery

I want to modify

```
$.fn.submit
```

function to some other function while the newly defined function should have access to the Scope of the original function.

```
 $.fn.submit=function(a,c){// ...codes here....//return something;}
```

I want to modify this function to something like this

```
 $.fn.submit_new = function(a,c){// modifed code, access variable in the Scope of $.fn.submit //return something;}
```

And I want the new function submit_new() to have full access to the Scope of $.fn.submit.  I tried extending it, not working. Simple copy is destroying the Scope.

Would be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by changing the prototype of jquery.prototype.submit to refer to your custom function. Then, in your custom function you can call the original one by applying it on the the caller.

```
var originalFunc = $.prototype.submit;

$.prototype.submit = function () {
  //do something

  originalFunc.apply(arguments.callee.caller);
}
```

Comment: this destroys scope

Comment: I tried ur code, please see the edited question, not working, b is in the Scope of original function $.fn.submit

Comment: @user3001408 first of all by adding my code to your question, you have invalidated my answer. People who read my answer now, won't vote up because they won't see any improvement relative to what you wrote. Now regarding 'b' - if you can't reach it using 'this.b' then it's not on the socpe, but in the closure. I've answered your question regarding remaining the original scope. You should now accept it and open a new question regarding reaching others'  closure variables. Also, you better remove my answer code from your question because invalidating answers is against SO rules.

Comment: @user3001408 It's rather challenging and I'm not sure if it's possible at all, but it might be somehow. I would open a new question, focused on this issue, and including the "javascript" tag in order to draw the attention of the right experts for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try extend() to extend the original jquery functions

`jQuery.fn.extend();`

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.fn.extend/